# "Rejected" suggested edit as "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit" - show "dismissed" instead of "rejected"

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I am going to make a "traffic-light" diagram of the final result status of the suggested edits:

**Red** (Bad) edits:

- Reject
- Reject and Edit

**Yellow** (Neutral) edits:

- Reject as "this edit conflicted with a subsequent edit"

**Green** (Good) edits:

- Improve Edit
- Approve

The "yellow" result does not even count towards the edit ban at all.  But the thing is, that it is marked as "rejected" in the user's activity and in the counts that are shown when clicking the "more" link on a review item from that user ("[x] had [y] edits approved and [z] edits rejected"), just like the "red" ones that **do** count towards the ban.  So I would like the "yellow" to be marked as **"dismissed"** instead of "rejected", since it is considered neutral.

---

This is just like the flags:

**Red** (Bad) flags:

- Declined

**Yellow** (Neutral) flags:

- Disputed

**Green** (Good) flags:

- Helpful

---

So I want it to be:

- Red: Reject, Reject and Edit
- Yellow: Dismiss
- Green: Improve Edit, Approve